# Find the dimension of intersection of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If
$$
\begin{align}
W_1 &=\{(x, y, z)| x + y- z =0\}\\
W_2 &= \{(x, y, z)| 3x +y- 2z =0\}\\
W_3 &=\{(x, y, z)| x -7y+3z =0\}
\end{align}
$$
then find $\dim (W_1 \cap W_2 \cap W_3 )$ and $\dim (W_1 \cap W_2 ).$

Comment: I tried to find the set of points (x,y,z) which satisfy all the three equations. Doing that I got the following relations
x = y,
z = 2y,
Hence (x,y,z) = y(1,1,2) 
Thus the dimension of the intersection of the three subspaces is 1.
For the dimension of the intersection of the first two subspaces, I followed the same approach. Tried to find the (x,y,z) by solving the first two equations. I got the same result. Dimension is 1. 
Is this the correct approach for such problems?

Comment: What relations? It's always better to show your work and where you got stuck.

Comment: Your solution is correct. If you exploit the relations of $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$, you find that $x=y$ and $z=2y=2x$. This means that the subspace $W_{1} \cap W_{2}$ is generated by the vector $(1,1,2)$ as you write. In particular, $\text{dim}(W_{1} \cap W_{2})=1$. Because $W_{1} \cap W_{2} \cap W_{3}$ is a subspace of $W_{1} \cap W_{2}$, $\text{dim}(W_{1} \cap W_{2} \cap W_{3}) \le \text{dim}(W_{1} \cap W_{2})$. But as you note, the third equation adds no new relations, so the dimensions are equal.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's more practical to solve these problems using row reduction, as it simplifies the computation.